# How to set task via command line to run if in sleep

Tags: windows-7, windows-runtime

I am scheduling a task in windows 7 via psexec to networked computers. The task is scheduled ok but I want to be able to set it to wake the PC if it is in sleep mode. I don't see anything in the docs on how to do that. Does anyone have anyway of doing this?

Comment: @SLaks I originally started with that solution , and was able to have it wake the PC s with WoL,  but I would like to just schedule the task and have the box checked that says to wake the PC to run the task. I have to distribute it to several sites and wanted the simpler solution.